# Boxplot for each row of a data

Tags: r, loops, matrix, boxplot

I am working in R. I have got three matrices: d1, d2, d3 and want to produce a boxplot from each row of the matrix. Like this: `boxplot(d1[1,], d2[1,], d3[1,])`.

How would it be possible to automatically produce the plot for each row of the matrix. Do I need a loop? Could the apply function help me? Additionally it would be great to plot 12 boxplots in one plotting window.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: why don't you "tidy" data first? You are using a row for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example of what I think you want. Assuming you have three 4x40 matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow = 4)
d2 <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow = 4)
d3 <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow = 4)
```

You should organize first your data, e.g. stacking them and adding a column:

```
d <- rbind(t(d1), t(d2), t(d3))
d <- cbind(d, rep(1:3, each = 10))
```

Now you can plot the three first colunmns boxplots:

```
boxplot(d[, 1] ~ d[, 5])
```

[image: boxplot 1]

If you want four for each matrix you can use a loop:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,1))
for (i in 1:4){
  boxplot(d[, i] ~ d[, 5])  
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image: boxplot 2]

But, if you want more impressive graphics, try either the lattice or the ggplot2 packages.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `boxplot` on the transposed matrix:

```
# Create some faux data
x <- matrix(rnorm(50), 5, 10, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:10]))

# Transpose and plot
boxplot(t(x), col = rainbow(5))
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thats unfortunately not the major problem. I want the boxplot to include only one row of each matrix. So for Plot A: row 1 of Matrix A, B, C. For Plot B: rwo 2 of Matrix A, B, C. and so on... 

Do I need a loop in that part (replacing `boxplot(d1[1,], d2[1,], d3[1,])` with `boxplot(d1[2,], d2[2,], d3[2,])`)

I will end up with 100 plot thats why I would prefer to plot 12 plots in one plotting window.

Comment: @user2978751 I slightly misread. As others have shown, it's easy to make 100 boxplots. But 100 plots is a lot as you imply -- but I fail to see how you want to fit it into 12 plots. I only see two possibilities: (a) 3 plots with 100 boxes, which was what I tried to imply by my post and (b) 100 plots with 3 boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
# your matrices (you have 5 variables and 20 observations per matrix, so you'll have to transpose)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 20)
m2 <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 20)
m3 <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 20)

# tidy data
library(reshape2)
Df <- melt(list(data.frame(t(m1)), data.frame(t(m2)), data.frame(t(m3))))

# boxplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = Df, aes(L1, value, color = factor(L1))) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]